# Change Scope of File and Printer sharing firewall exception in Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, file-sharing, windows-firewall

Windows XP was easy in this regard, go to properties and change scope of "File and Printer Sharing" in Windows Firewall and just change the scope easily but in Vista I have to Windows Firewall with Advanced Security and change the scope for each individual rule manually for each rule relevant to File and Printer Sharing as the previous way prevents you from changing scope. I don't have time to do this for all the computers I need to do this for in this ADless network, is there a way just as easy as Windows XP to change the scope for everything related to File and Printer sharing on Windows Vista?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's depreciated, I used netsh firewall to do it easily instead. In my case, all I wanted to do was change the scope to include a non-local subnet of 10.0.0.0/8.

```
netsh firewall set service type=FILEANDPRINT scope=CUSTOM addresses="LocalSubnet,10.0.0.0/8"
```

netsh advfirewall doesn't allow 'set' filtering by group name, because that would make life easy, you would have to set it rule by rule one by one. So deprecated method it is, like ease-of-use I guess.